# Multiple Instances of CakePHP in same directory

Tags: php, cakephp

I have copied a CakePHP site into several different directories and was able to get each of them working, but this latest time the site displays the correct Views, but the Models and Controllers from the original site.

There don't seem to be any obvious setting that points to the original site. Any ideas where I might look to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check **.htaccess**, if it does none exist then build one.

Comment: So the 3 .htaccess files are all identical to the ones used on the working sites, with the directories changed to reflect the new site

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: It could be that the front controller needs a ReWriteCond and ReWriteRule edit  because the two copies of the websites are in different directories, some other stuff in .htaccess could  also be the culprit so joshv2 might be right about his comment.

Answer (score 0):

> this is easier than reprogramming the original site to display more than one language

That can be true, it doesn't make any sense and causes *more* work at the end. If the code is not an unbelievable pile of fail this can't be true.

If you duplicate the code, you'll always have to maintain *two* repos or branches, manage *two* sites and merge fixes between both. It's just silly to duplicate a whole app just because of translations.

How is that more hard than just adding `__('Translateable string goes here')` and if needed [the TranslateableBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html) to the existing application? Getting the language in the URL, a problem? [No, it's not](http://florian-kraemer.net/2015/07/cakephp-3-0-i18n-language-inside-the-url/).

[Read that whole chapter](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html) of the book before sticking to your weird idea.

We're running a site with 18 languages, Chinese, Russisan, English... and using everything I named before that the framework offers. All in the very same code base and the app was migrated from 1.3 to 2.x and now to 3.x.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, I'm just telling you how my client wanted me to do it.

Comment: This was not clear for me based on your question. Well, next advice: Get  rid of that client. Clients who think they know it better than the person they hire to solve their problem are usually troublesome.