# Multiple instances of cakephp cross-talking

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

I'm running CakePHP 1.3 and have two instances of the exact same code running on the same server which I access from slightly different URLs on the same domain.

One is a test version, and the other is the production version.  This way, I can edit the test version, test my changes in the browser, push the changes to github, and pull them to the production repo when I'm happy.

My issue is that the controllers (and likely models) seem to be cross-talking somehow.
Changes to my views are not reflected on the live repo, as expected.
Changes to the controller code are instantly effective in the live repo.

I am quite new to coding so I apologize for missing anything obvious.

During my background research I discovered that no, sessions are not being shared and the most relevant question was obliquely answered: [Multiple Instances of CakePHP in same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203958/multiple-instances-of-cakephp-in-same-directory?newreg=8a731456651549a18d0fd2a3c3a224d1) and not quite relevant to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to modify the apps to use different cache configurations, and specifically ensure the cache prefix is different, as otherwise they could be poisoning the cache for each other.

I would also recommend clearing cache on every deploy so as to avoid generic cache issues in the future.